# Why are 2 kotlin descending IntRanges equal?

Tags: kotlin, range, equals

It appears kotlin considers different valued descending IntRanges as equal. Is this because they are all considered invalid?

```
@Test
fun abc() {
    var a:IntRange = (1..2)
    var b:IntRange = (1..3)
    println(a==b) // prints false
    var c:IntRange = (10..1)
    var d:IntRange = (9..1)
    println(c==d) // prints true
    println(c) // prints 10..1
    println(d) // prints 9..1
}
```

Comment: They are not descending ranges. Both `10..1` and `9..1` result in an empty range. Use `downTo` to get a descending range: `10 downTo 1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for the [`IntRange.isEmpty`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.ranges/-int-range/is-empty.html) says:

> The range is empty if its start value is greater than the end value.

Therefore, both `10..1` and `9..1` will be empty ranges, and [empty ranges are considered equal in the current implementation of `equals`](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/80cce1dc5280eb9135390270c8644a7b8d198071/core/builtins/src/kotlin/Ranges.kt#L57).

If you want a sequence that goes from 10 *down to* 1, you might be looking for the [`downTo`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.ranges/down-to.html) infix function instead. Note that this gives you a more general `IntProgression`, not an `IntRange`.

```
val from10To1 = 10 downTo 1
```

Comment: Is there a more authoritative source for empty ranges being equal?  (The library's implementation can change, while its doc comments, the language spec, language reference, and other official documentation is part of the public API so much less likely to.)

Comment: @gidds I was trying to find something more authoritative too, but couldn't, but I still decided to post the link to the source here, as it still explains the output of OP's code _as of right now_. Edited to clarify.